# In ANTLR how do I parse streams against a specific low-level rule?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

ANTRLR newbie question. Say for a given grammar ANTLR maven plugin has created all the necessary Java classes to traverse and parse a text. And it works just fine when used as prescribed in "The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference".

Now imagine I need to reuse the generated classes to parse an expression which is defined by a rule buried somewhere deep in the grammar file.
However the Reference doesn't seem to provide a clue as to how to select a specific rule as a starting one, the generated classes always expect the whole grammar tree being present in the source.

Using the generated classes as-is doesn't work either, cause the corresponding listener and parser methods expect a context parameter which can only be created when having a "parent context" and an "invoking state" which I don't know how to define.

The only (and rubbish) solution I came up with so far, is splitting the grammar into two files so that the low-level rule in question would become top-level one, and import the latter into the first.

Do I miss something obvious here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple. Load your input stream with the text that you wanna match against one of the subrules, then call the function for that subrule in the parser as you did with the main rule. Each grammar rule is represented by a function, which you can simply call for your subtext and it will generate a stripped down parse tree then, which applies only to this subrule (and it's children).